# Parent with automatic weights problem in Blender

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, parent, vertex-groups

I am rigging a character for an animated short in Blender 2.82, but then this happend:
[image]
On the other hand it looks as it shouldt, but here something went wrong. Do anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: you need to give some corrections to the wrist in weight paint mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! I had already parentet the mesh to the armature erlier. Later I flipped the names from L to R. Then I parentet it again, and it had still saved some of the old vertex groups. I deleted all the vertex groups, and now it works:)